# Angular 2 unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a service in Angular 2 using jasmine and need to add an array of JSON data in body parameter for the Response Options class, I have tried various approaches and failed miserably please see the code snippet below:

```
it('returns a list of employees with correct first-employee data', done => {
        //Arrange
        mockBackend.connections.subscribe((c: any) => {
            let response = new ResponseOptions({
                body: `[
                            {
                                travelReasonId:1,
                                name:'Operator visit'
                            },
                            {
                                travelReasonId:2,
                                name:'3rd Party visit'
                            },
                            {
                                travelReasonId:3,
                                name:'MGS visit'
                            }
                        ]`
            });
            c.mockRespond(new Response(response));
        });
        // Act   
        let result: any;
        travelReasonService.getAllTravelReasons()
            .subscribe((_result) => { result = _result; });
        // Assert
          let firstValue = {
            travelReasonId: 1,
            name: 'Operator visit'
         };
        console.log(result);
        expect(result[0]).toEqual(firstValue);
        expect(result.length).toEqual(3);
    });
```

The test result states that SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected '}' (line 321) when a run the test for the code in question,Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Well, your body is not valid JSON. keys and string values must be enclosed in double quotes. Why don't you just create a JavaScript array of objects, and then call JSON.stringify() to get valid JSON?

Comment: Hey JB Nizet thanks for the suggestion, it solved the problem I was having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below for the solution I implemented which was suggested by JB Nizet

```
 it('returns a list with two employees', done => {
        //Arrange
        let travelReasons: TravelReason[];
        travelReasons = [];
        let travelReason_1 = new TravelReason();
        let travelReason_2 = new TravelReason();
        travelReason_1.name = 'Operator visit';
        travelReason_1.travelReasonId = 1;
        travelReason_2.name = '3rd Party visit';
        travelReason_2.travelReasonId = 2;
        travelReasons.push(travelReason_1);
        travelReasons.push(travelReason_2);

        mockBackend.connections.subscribe((c: any) => {
            let response = new ResponseOptions({
                body: JSON.stringify(travelReasons)
            });
            c.mockRespond(new Response(response));
        });
        // Act           
        let result: any;
        travelReasonService.getAllTravelReasons()
            .subscribe((_result) => { result = _result; });

        // Assert
        let firstValue = {
            travelReasonId: 1,
            name: 'Operator visit'
        };

        let secondValue = {
            'travelReasonId': 2,
            'name': '3rd Party visit'
        };

        expect(result[0]).toEqual(firstValue);
        expect(result[1]).toEqual(secondValue);
        expect(result.length).toEqual(2);
        done();
    });
```